Is there only one zero vector?
I was recently given the following question in a quiz:

Define $W$ to be the set of ordered pairs $(x_1, x_2)$, where $x_1$ can be any real number, but $x_2$ must be a positive real number. Define $\oplus$ on $W$ by: $$(x_1,x_2)\oplus(y_1, y_2) = (x_1+y_1, x_2y_2)$$


Axiom 3 (A3): There exists an element $\vec{0}$ {with a vector symbol above it} so that $\vec{x}\oplus\vec{0}=\vec{x}$ for all $\vec{x}$.

My approach was to show that when using the $\oplus$ operation between any vector $(x_1,x_2)$ and the zero vector $(0, 0)$ the resultant vector is $(x_1, 0)$, which is NOT the same as $(x_1, x_2)$. Therefore, I concluded that the axiom does not hold.
The zero vector is $(0, 0)$, right?
However, the solution states that:

Since $(x_1, x_2)\oplus (0, 1) = (x_1, x_2)$, the axiom is satisfied

The solution for the question use $(0, 1)$ as the example to show that the axiom does indeed hold. I am confused as to where they got $(0, 1)$ from because that is not the zero vector.
Can the zero vector ever NOT be $(0,0)$? I understand in the case of this question that the vector space contains $(x_1, x_2)$ where $x_1$ is any real number but $x_2$ must be a POSITIVE real number. $0$ is not a positive real number, so therefore $(0, 0)$ doesn't exist within the vector space. But then that also means that there is no zero vector to prove/disprove A3 in the first place!
If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.
I would tag images however because this is a new account I do not have the ability to do so.

Not sure I follow. Were you asked to prove an axiom?

The "zero vector" just means the additive identity. Does the zero vector have to be composed by zeroes only?

If $0$ and $0'$ are two zero vectors, then $0=0+0'=0'$.

Notice that the map $f: (x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1, log(x_2))$ is a bijection from $W$ to the usual $\mathbb R^2$ which commutes with the defined $\oplus$, i.e. $f(a \oplus b) = f(a) + f(b)$ where the $+$ is the usual addition on $\mathbb R^2$. This means the "zero vector" asked here will be an element such that $f( \vec 0 ) = (0, 0)$

The ordered pair $(0,0)$ is not even in $W$ since the second value "must be a positive real number". The number $0$ is not positive.

In this problem, $\vec{0}$ is presumably just meant as an arbitrary symbol.  You cannot assume that it means the ordered pair $(0,0)$.
In the context of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its usual vector space structure, then $\vec{0}$ would refer to the additive identity element of the vector space ("the zero vector"), which is indeed $(0,0)$.  But here we are deliberately not using the usual vector space structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but rather endowing it with an unusual operation.

So, in that case, the "zero vector" is essentially just the vector through which the axioms hold?

@AndreAthari: Right.

That's why, in the context of group theory, you usually denote the neutral element with $e$.

@Toffomat We use $0$ for the identity in additive abelian groups.

I think that thinking about "vectors" and "vector spaces" is a bit misleading here. $W$ is called "set of ordered pairs", on which a certain operation is defined; $\vec 0$ is called "an element" of that set (formally you could write it as $\vec 0 \in (W,\oplus)$). Nothing in the question talks about "vector spaces".

@printf: Not in the part quoted, at least.  But if I'm not mistaken, this set does become a vector space if endowed with the provided group operation $\oplus$ and the scalar multiplication $c\cdot (x_1, x_2) = (cx_1, x_2^c)$.  (It's isomorphic to the usual $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1, \log x_2)$.)  That may have been the broader context of the question.  Just a guess, though.

That's true, but the more I think about it, the more I think this is actually an exercise in group theory rather than vector algebra. The very fact that the "axiom" in the question is called "Axiom 3" suggests that there might have been several axioms: (1) closure (if $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ are in $W$, then so is $(x_1,x_2)\oplus(y_1,y_2)$; (2) associativity; (3) existence of the identity element (that's what this question is about); (4) existence of inverses. But, again, this is all guesses and speculations.

@printf: There's a version of the question on Chegg (it seems one of OP's classmates is cheating) that references vector spaces explicitly: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/define-w-set-ordered-pts-define-w-set-ordered-pairs-x-1-x-2-x-1-real-number-x-2-must-posit-q201946272

@NateEldredge Yes, it appears you are right. That question does include another operation, multiplication by a scalar, $\odot$, which does indeed make $W$ into a vector space...

@JohnDouma Of course, once you've chosen to write the group operation as $+$, it makes sense to write the neutral element as $0$.

The "trick" in this question is to recognize that the choice of symbols is arbitrary, and the "zero" means "additive zero under a funky/given definition of addition" rather than "origin". Thus, the "zero" is just "a vector of interest" and to avoid confusion, it's best to mentally subsitute it with something else. I read the problem as:
$$\begin{aligned}
a,c &\in \mathbb R,\\
b,d &\in \mathbb R^+\\
(a,b)\oplus(c,d) &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} (a+c,b\times d).\\
\forall\, \vec x\in(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^+)\ 
\exists\, \vec v\in(\mathbb R, \mathbb R^+) &:\  \vec x \oplus \vec v = \vec x.
\end{aligned}$$
We can rewrite the axiom with explicit vector elements:
$$\begin{aligned}
\forall_{x_1,x_2}\ \exists_{v_1,v_2}:(x_1,x_2)\oplus(v_1,v_2)&=(x_1,x_2),\\
\text{ thus by definition}\\
\forall_{x_1,x_2}\ \exists_{v_1,v_2}:(x_1+v_1,x_2\times v_2)&=(x_1,x_2).
\end{aligned}$$
Since vector equality works element-wise:
$$\begin{aligned}
\forall\, x_1 \in\mathbb R \ \exists\,  v_1\in\mathbb R   &: x_1=x_1+v_1\\
\forall\, x_2 \in\mathbb R^+\ \exists\, v_2\in\mathbb R^+ &: x_2=x_2\times v_2,
\end{aligned}$$
which holds for $v=(v_1,v_2):v_1=0,\ v_2=1$.

Maybe a typo, but I think the axiom is $\exists v \forall x$ rather than the other way around.

Every vector space has one (and only one) origin, also known as a "zero vector" and denoted as $\vec 0$, because it behaves in vector addition like the number zero behaves in normal addition.  That is, for every vector $\vec x$ in the vector space, $\vec x + \vec 0 = \vec x$, i.e. $\vec 0$ acts as the additive identity element in the vector space.
However, two vector spaces do not need to have the same origin.  Indeed, in some sense this is true even for the "traditional" Euclidean vector spaces.  For example, the origin of $\mathbb R^2$ is $(0, 0)$, while the origin of $\mathbb R^3$ is $(0, 0, 0)$.  Obviously these are not the same vector, since they have a different number of dimensions!
Nor is it in any way required for the origin of a vector space to be represented as a tuple of zeros.  That's precisely the point of your exercise: it's possible to define a two-dimensional vector space whose origin is $(0, 1)$ by defining vector addition (and scalar multiplication) in that space in a suitable way that makes $(0, 1)$ the additive identity in that vector space.
In fact, it's not even necessary for any element of a vector space to be representable as a finite tuple of numbers!  A common example is the vector space of real-valued functions over the reals, denoted as $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, whose vectors are functions of the form $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, with vector addition and scalar multiplication defined pointwise (i.e. $f + g$ is defined as the function $x \mapsto f(x) + g(x)$, and $a \cdot f$ as the function $x \mapsto a \cdot f(x)$).  The "zero vector" of this vector space is then the function $x \mapsto 0$ that maps every real number $x$ to zero.

Ps. It's easy to prove that a vector space can have at most one zero vector, since if $\vec 0_a$ and $\vec 0_b$ were both zero vectors of the same vector space, then we'd have $\vec 0_a = \vec 0_a + \vec 0_b = \vec 0_b$.  The fact that a vector space must have at least one zero vector, however, must be taken as an axiom, i.e. as part of the definition of what constitutes a vector space.  In particular, there are structures known as affine spaces that behave in many respects like vector spaces, except that they have no zero vector.
